# How do I make my UDF using Randomize to be non-volatile?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a function that creates random IDs for me.

When using it in Excel, the ID column will be populated with: =UPPER(CONCATENATE(LEFT([@Group],4),RandomString(4)))

Unless the length input (4) in Random String changes, I do not want the Randomise part of the formula to ever re-calculate again (I am never going to change the length, so it will be static). The only characters that should change are the ones related to (LEFT([@Group],4).

Right now all cells in my TaskID column recalculate when I change any cell in the Group Column, so the application volatile is not really helpful enough.

Thanks

```
Function RandomString(Length As Integer)

Application.Volatile False

Dim CharacterBank As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim str As String

'Test Length Input
  If Length < 1 Then
    MsgBox "Length variable must be greater than 0"
    Exit Function
  End If

CharacterBank = Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", _
  "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", _
  "W", "X", "Y", "Z")
  

'Randomly Select Characters One-by-One

  For x = 1 To Length
    Randomize
    str = str & CharacterBank(Int((UBound(CharacterBank) - LBound(CharacterBank) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(CharacterBank)))
  Next x

'Output Randomly Generated String
  RandomString = str


End Function
```

Comment: You can never rely on a UDF not recalculating, so this approach is not going to work.

Comment: As Tim says. Not a good idea. Use a worksheet event instead as the trigger. Like cell select and if target.value = "" then "random string"

Comment: You`ll have to store the value somewhere. Some options: 1) a Static variable  (won't survive a Workbook close reopen) 2) store in another cell (UDFs can't directly write to cells, but work arounds exist) 3) registry 4) external file 5) [customxmlparts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.customxmlpart.load) (I am not sure that UDFs can access these)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, based on the fact that the sentiment was this was not a good way to go about it, I have done the following instead: =IF(C16="","",UPPER(LEFT([@Group],4)&TEXT(ROW()-15,"000")))